# PHP Faker generate unique dates in range

Tags: php, laravel, faker

I'm trying to generate a unique sequence of dates in a Laravel Factory. e.g.:

```
2019-05-04
2019-05-05
2019-05-06
...
2019-07-04
```

I tried this, and each date appears 0 - n times.

```
$faker->unique()->dateTimeBetween('-7 days', '+2 months')->format('Y-m-d'),
```

Answer (score 15):

Why don't you try this most random date time like below :

```
        'created_at' => $faker->dateTimeThisMonth(),
```

and for some time as documentation says you must do like below :

```
$this->faker->unique()->dateTimeBetween($startDate = '-30 years', $endDate = 'now', $timezone = null) // DateTime('2003-03-15 02:00:49', 'Africa/Lagos')
```

here is a link to it :

```
https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#fakerproviderdatetime
```

so in your case it

```
$this->faker->unique()->dateTimeInInterval($startDate = '-7 days', $interval = '+ 5 days', $timezone = null)
```

Comment: This is not answering the question.  It produces a dateTIME, and so using the `unique()` modifier can still produce up to 86,400 duplicate values for a single date.